# How to complete search in firebase i.e inside every nodes and sub-nodes and even sub-sub nodes if available

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

How to search in nodes and sub sub nodes because there are different users with different various types of ids inside
I have done this:

```
public int finddupuser(final String name){

        final int[] check = {0};
        mUserDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    alladmin fam_mem=userSnapshot.getValue(alladmin.class);

                    if(fam_mem.getName().equals(name)) {
                        check[0] =1;
                    }
                    for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot2: userSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        allfamily fam_mem2=userSnapshot2.getValue(allfamily.class);
                        if(fam_mem2.getName().equals(name)) {
                            check[0] =1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        Toast.makeText(this, "find="+check[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return check[0];
    }
```

But it is not checking in sub-sub nodes

my json file looks like this

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "gptshubham595" : {
      "familymember" : {
        "11111" : {
          "name" : "ABCD"
             "22222":{
           "name" : "ABCDE"
           }
        }
      },
      "TOTAL_FAMILY_MEMBER" : "1",
      "name" : "ABC",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have better if you have added the `POJO` classes for `alladmin` and `allfamily`. 
And the `json` file you have added seems to be in an incorrect format. At least it is missing few brackets and commas.

Anyways, What you are trying to do is clear. But the method you've used is not necessary and bit of unclear. If you have created the `POJO` classes correctly, you can do something like below. For ease of mine, i'll add my own definition of `POJO` classes below. You can get the idea from it and modify it as you want.

**AllAdmin.java**

```
public class AllAdmin {
  private String name = '';
  private List<AllFamily> familyMembers = null;
  private String totalFamilyNumber = ''; //Here you may use the preferred data type, i'll use string for ease.

  public AllAdmin() {};

  public void setName(String name) {this.name = name};
  public String getName(){return this.name};

  public void setFamilyMembers(List<AllFamily> members) {
      if (familyMembers == null) {
         familyMembers = new ArrayList<AllFamily>();
      }
      //This part depends on how you want to add new members.
      familyMember.addAll(members); 
  }
  public List<AllFamily> getFamilyMembers() {
      if(familyMembers != null){
         return this.familyMembers;
      } else {
         return new ArrayList<AllFamily>();
      }
  }

  public void setTotalFamilyNumber(String number){this.totalFamilyNumber = number};
  public String getTotalFamilyNumber(){return this.totalFamilyNumber}
}
```

**AllFamily.Java**

```
public class AllFamily{
  private String name = '';
  //Is this all(if so use of separate POJO class is unnecessary), this node is not clear in the json you've added.
  public AllFamily(){};

  public void setName(String name) {this.name = name};
  public String getName(){return this.name};
}
```

Then to the querying part. Additionally i have used `boolean` for conditional states. Also make a note of simple java naming conventions i've used with camel-case syntax's. Following these conventions is not necessary, but it improves the readability of a code and comes handy in these kind of platforms since it improves the possibility of understanding the code just by reading it.

```
public boolean findDupUser(final String name){

final boolean[] check = {false};
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
mUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             AllAdmin allAdmin = userSnapshot.getValue(AllAdmin.class);
             if(allAdmin.getName().equals(name) || allAdmin.getFamilyMembers().contains(name)) {
                check[0] = true;                    
             }
        }
     }
});
Toast.makeText(this, "find="+check[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return check[0];
}
```

**Note**: Above code is for the logic of checking whether an individual already exists in the database as an user himself or as a family member of an existing user.